# How to make a navbar appear in certain section of the page? (bootstrap too)

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, frontend

I'm making a website and when he in mobile mode (> 767px) will see a navbar. I already got it, but I want this navbar to appear ONLY after the section 1.

By default, the navbar appears all the time. I want it to appear ONLY when I see the Section 2.

Please, see the example below:

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/gtw7375/3zc5Ltzp/

HTML:

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-bottom visible-xs">
  <div class="container-fluid"> 

    <div class="navbar-header">
         <!-- <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">LOGO PSTCH</a> </div> -->


    <div class="collapse navbar-collapse visible-xs" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
      <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
       <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal1" data-direction="bottom"> About</a></li>
       <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal2" data-direction='bottom'> Sobre </a></li>
       <li><a  href="#" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal3" data-direction='bottom'> Contact </a></li>


      </ul>    
    </div>
    </div>  
  </div> 
</nav>

 <div id="logo"> 

            <center>
                            <a href="#desce" class="page-scroll  btn btn-xl">SECTION 1</a>
            </center>
  </div>

  <div id="content">

    <p> SECTION 2  </p>

      <p> The navbar will appear here down/hereafter!</p>
  </div>
```

CSS:

```
html, body {
    height:100%;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;

}


#logo{
            background: black;
            width: 100%;
            height: 100%;          


}

#content {
        border: 1px solid black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 50%;
}

.navbar .nav  li{
    float:none;
    display:inline-block;
    *display:inline; /* Internet Explorer 7 compatibility */
    *zoom:1;
    vertical-align: bottom;

}


.navbar .navbar-collapse {
  text-align: center;
}
```

How can I do that?

Comment: Please include all relevant code in your post and **don't** just include a link to a code hosting site. Your post should stand alone from any other resource; consider what would happen if that site went down in the future!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using [JQuery](https://jquery.com/), you can listen for the window's scroll event, check if it has scrolled beyond the element's top offset and take action accordingly.  The following is Javascript code that makes use of the JQuery plugin.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $(".navbar").hide(); //Hide the navigation bar first

    $(window).scroll(function () {  //Listen for the window's scroll event
        if (isScrolledAfterElement("#content")) { //if it has scrolled beyond the #content elment
            $('.navbar').fadeIn();  //Show the navigation bar
        } else {
            $('.navbar').fadeOut(); //Else hide it
        }
    });

    //Function that returns true if the window has scrolled beyond the given element
    function isScrolledAfterElement(elem) {
        var $elem = $(elem);
        var $window = $(window);

        var docViewTop = $window.scrollTop();
        var docViewBottom = docViewTop + $window.height();

        var elemTop = $elem.offset().top;

        return elemTop <= docViewBottom;
    }
});
```

You can see this in action in this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/pavorestis/0uok0oof/).  I removed the **visible-xs** class from the navigation bar and also added a **margin-bottom** attribute to the **#logo** element to make the effect noticeable to all users (You don't have to do this to your project).

Answer (score 0):

I don't really understand what you want to do with your code.

```
<div id="box01">
     <p>This will be hidden, only visible after 767px.</p>
</div>

.box01 {
    display: none;
}
@media screen and (max-width : 767px) {
    .box01 {
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Comment: I want the navbar to appear ONLY when the page stow in Section 2. As in the example. Understand?